# Testing singular resource controller with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have defined a singular resource in my `routes.rb` which looks like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :dog, only: [:create], to: "dog#create", controller: "dog"
end
```

After that I've defined a controller with a create action like this

```
class DogController < ApplicationController
  def create
    render json: {}, status: :ok
  end
end
```

And now I'm trying to test it out with RSpec like this

```
require "rails_helper"

describe DogController do
  it "works" do
    post :create, params: { foo: :bar }
  end
end
```

This is throwing this error instead of passing:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"dog", :foo=>:bar}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to

```
resource :dog, only: [:create], :controller => "dog"
```

It is better to use plural controllers even if its a singular resource

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Comment: it's passing if I change controller name to `DogsController`, but I would really like to keep it singular and I would hate to change names of my controllers just to appease testing framework

Comment: removing `to:` argument makes it work as a singular, so I edited your question

Answer (score 0):

Your create action is not taking in any parameter. It's just rendering json and returning a status code