# Rails 5 Rspec ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Searched through other similar questions on here, and they all seem to be related to a malformed request of some sort (Not providing an `id`, or not including the params correctly) but those don't seem to be the problem I'm having.

The route definitely exists, going to the route in the browser works just fine. Page loads, everything. But Rspec is giving me a UrlGenerationError for some reason.

I've tried manually specifying the controller name in the routes, changing to a pluralized controller, and even using a different (pluralized) controller. It's seeming like there is an issue with some other configuration somewhere, but the error that it's a URLGeneration error is extremely unhelpful. I would greatly appreciate any other ideas.

We have API controller specs elsewhere in our app that seem to be functioning correctly, but I cannot tell the difference in set up between those and this one.

My error:

```
  1) Spaceman::ReputationEnhancementsController GET show has a 200 status code
     Failure/Error: get :show

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"spaceman/reputation_enhancements"}
     # ./spec/controllers/spaceman/reputation_enhancements_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.14 seconds (files took 6.13 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/spaceman/reputation_enhancements_controller_spec.rb:9 # Spaceman::ReputationEnhancementsController GET show has a 200 status code
```

Routes:

```
Spaceman::Engine.routes.draw do
  resource :reputation_enhancement, path: "reputation-enhancement", only: [ :show, :create ] do
    get :filter
  end
end
```

Test: (I've tried added `type: :controller` here, as well as fully qualifying, adding `Rspec.describe` instead, etc...)

```
require "rails_helper"

describe Spaceman::ReputationEnhancementsController do

  describe "GET show" do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :show
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end

end
```

`rake routes`

```
filter_reputation_enhancement GET    /reputation-enhancement/filter(.:format) spaceman/reputation_enhancements#filter
       reputation_enhancement GET    /reputation-enhancement(.:format)        spaceman/reputation_enhancements#show
                              POST   /reputation-enhancement(.:format)        spaceman/reputation_enhancements#create
```

EDIT:

I've tried manually specifying the controller name in the routes, changing to a pluralized controller, and even using a different (pluralized) controller. It's seeming like there is an issue with some other configuration somewhere, but the error that it's a URLGeneration error is extremely unhelpful. I would greatly appreciate any other ideas.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978962/testing-singular-resource-controller-with-rspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the issue was that the Controller was part of a gem and the routes to access the controller were not included by default.

Solved by adding `routes { Spaceman::Engine.routes }` to the top inside of the main `describe` block.

It's all fine to leave singular routes and everything else was set up correctly. Just had to include the routes.

Comment: Thanks, `routes { Rails.application.routes }` works. Is there a convenient way to do this? It's annoying to add this for all `describe` block.

Comment: Hm. I didn't look much deeper into, I'm sorry. I do image there is a way to configure some sort of option in rspec to set that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the singular `resource` in your routes but your spec is requesting the plural form “reputation_enhancement**s**”.

See [this bit in the routing guide for singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) and [this long standing issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769) in the Rails issue tracker that explains that there's no good way to get `url_for` to map back to a singular resource.

To resolve it, either specify the path in your spec or add a plural route.

Comment: Where is the spec requesting the plural form? The controller is supposed to be pluralized even with a singular route, if that's what you were referring to- so I'm not sure where the pluralization is messed up?

Comment: Switched all of the references to the Controller to singular (by manually assigning the controller in the routes) and the problem still exists.

Comment: @Rockster160 I added some more info for you.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using plural resources. (Switched to a different controller to try to test, but it's still failing with the same error)

Comment: Is there a way to specify the path in my spec? I can't find a way to manually add in a path. I've made the route plural, I've tried making the controller singular, I've read through the other post you commented and didn't make any progress. (their issue was, again, invalid routing syntax- like most of the other posts I've seen that are similar to this one)